# How to run PHP Script from command on xampp apache server uunder linux - user/file permissions issue

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl, xampp

I am trying to run a PHP Script on my apache server installed with xampp under Linux but seem to have some user/file permissions issue. I have installed php cli and the path name is all correct.

My command is this and it does not do anything.

```
/usr/bin/php /home/eem/website/cron/cronjob_test.php
```

When I run it as wget or curl instead of php it executes correct. I know that curl+wget run with the apache user and php cli runs with the cron user.

So the fact that php does not execute should have something to do with the apache configuration in xampp or some user permissions but I really have no idea what the problem is.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: ls /home/eem/website/cron/cronjob_test.php  what it shows?

Comment: running it as php shows nothing in terminal. My var/log/syslog show s this: `May 14 06:27:57 eem-VirtualBox /usr/bin/crontab[31959]: (eem) LIST (eem)` but the website on xampp is not being changed...not sure if this is what you was asking about...